# How do I display a terminal banner after clearing the terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, figlet

so I set up my terminal banner with figlet and I really like it. But it will only be displayed after opening a new terminal. My question is: Can I somehow display a banner after I hit "clear"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to edit your .bashrc file and add the following line:

```
alias clear='clear && (the figlet command you use)'
```

Then it will start up every time you type clear.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: No need to use bracket though.